an easy way to record sleep with watch
I don't have a regular sleep schedule and I was looking for an easy way to record sleep activity.
I'm very new to Apple Watch and as best I can tell you have to go into setting->focus->sleep focus->next schedule and change the schedule.
What I'd like to do is just press a shortcut and have the watch start recording a sleep event.  Short of that, maybe just open the sleep settings so I can change the time to now.
Maybe even a "Siri set the sleep schedule to now" or something along those lines.
ChatGPT is suggesting that I make a shortcut to open settings (can't seem to get to settings->focus->sleep focus) so I was trying to do a custom gesture, but IDK how to select a specific item on each page.
Is there not an easier way to get the watch to record a sleep even that is NOT scheduled?
Kinda like "workout" where you tap the app, tap the kind of workout, then it just starts recording data.

My understanding is the watch automatically detects when you sleep, no need to tell it when you sleep. The schedule is so that the focus mode "sleep" is activated and does not disturb you and hopefully gets you to go to bed at the right times...
